# Custom function inside reduceByKey in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an array Array[(Int, String)] which consists of the key-value pairs for the entire dataset where key is the column number and value is column's value.

So, I want to use reduceByKey to perform certain operations like max,min,mean,median,quartile calculations by key.

How can I achieve this using reduceByKey as groupByKey spills a lot of data to the disk. How can I pass a custom function inside reduceByKey.

Or is there a better way to do this.

Thanks !!

Comment: How do you intend to calculate max, min, mean, etc. on String values?

Comment: reduceByKey already takes a (custom) function. So what  is your actual question?

Comment: @Paul...yes I can use a custom function inside reduceByKey to find min. But I want to calculate say min,max and mean inside a single custom function. Is it possible.
def myfunc(x: Double, y: Double) = {
    if(x > y)
       x
    else
      y
}

Comment: No, because your function needs to mapa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use combineByKey to track sum, count, min, max values, all in the same transformation. For that you need 3 functions:

- create combiner function - that will initialize the 'combined value' consisting of min, max etc
- merge values function - that will add another value to the 'combined value'
- merge combiners - that will merge two 'combined values' together

The second approach would be to use an Accumulable object, or several Accumulators.

Please, check the documentation for those. I can provide some examples, if necessary.

**Update:**

Here is an example to calculate average by key. You can expand it to calculate min and max, too:

```
def createComb = (v:Double) => (1, v)

def mergeVal:((Int,Double),Double)=>(Int,Double) =                     
         {case((c,s),v) => (c+1, s+v)}

def mergeComb:((Int,Double),(Int,Double))=>(Int,Double) =
         {case((c1,s1),(c2,s2)) => (c1+c2, s1+s2)}

val avgrdd = rdd.combineByKey(createComb, mergeVal, mergeComb, 
         new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(rdd.partitions.size))
         .mapValues({case(x,y)=>y/x})
```

Comment: I have understood how this is working but do I need to write three different functions for each operation like min, max etc. Bit confused how this can be done.